# Android how to animate objects sequentially

Tags: java, android, sequential, translate-animation

I want to animate some multiple objects sequentially. As in, one animation should happen right after the previous animation stops.

I was using TranslateAnimations but it appears that all animations happen at the same time. I then tried putting all TranslateAnimations into an AnimationSet but this doesn't do what I imagined it would do.

What is the proper way to have multiple translateAnimations happen one after the other. Since this will loop, I can't just mess around with the setDuration because they will eventually get out of sync

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an [AnimationListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.AnimationListener.html) to start the next animation after the previous one ends. This would make sure that only one runs at a time, and they go in the right order.

Comment: My animation "shakes" my acitivity if I do it sequentially for some reason: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18899280/multiple-xml-animation-is-not-working